# ListAdapters and WrapperListAdapter algorithm

Tags: java, android, listadapter

This logic is written in a function with signature

```
private void showDialog(final AdapterView<? extends Adapter> parent,
     String title, String message, final Tag subject)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
// refresh adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
if (parent.getAdapter() instanceof WrapperListAdapter) {
    adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) ((WrapperListAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter();
} else {
    adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
}
adapter.getCursor().requery();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, is there any point in having `AdapterView<? extends Adapter>` in the signature and not just `AdapterView<?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Hold onto your `Cursor` object and call `requery()` on it, rather than trying to dig it out from your adapter.

Also, ideally, you would not need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` -- `CursorAdapter` does this automatically, and hopefully the `WrapperListAdapter` will hook into the `CursorAdapter` and cascade the `notifyDataSetChanged()` operation.

> Also, is there any point in having
>   AdapterView in the
>   signature and not just AdapterView?

That syntax will throw a compiler error if you attempt to create an `AdapterView` on an `Integer`, or a `Button`, or a `Socket`. In other words, it adds a bit of compile-time type safety.